# Converting timeframe of a time series

Tags: programming, time-series

So I've encountered a problem - I have a lot of 1 min data, but my strategy works better on longer timeframes and backtrader has some problems with backtesting on 1 mln rows.

I want to convert it to 1h/4h/1d timeframes, tried to convert to 4h just by selecting every 240th candle but not sure that's the right way, any thoughts on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the open of the first candle, the high and low over all candles in the time frame and the close of the last candle.

[R has a package](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/xts/html/to.period.html) for this, your language of choice might have it as well.